# Cursor movement and text retrieval in input methods

Tags: android, ime

I'm designing my first Android IME and am a bit overwhelmed. My goals are accessibility-related, and as such I wonder if perhaps I'm trying things with the IME framework that just aren't possible. I've taken the default softkeyboard example and have it working along with some of my modifications, so I've definitely understood at least some of this, but there isn't a whole lot of documentation on some of the things I'm attempting. Here's what I mean:

Currently, Android phones with touchscreen-only keyboards are inaccessible. I currently have an accessible touchscreen keyboard using methods similar to those used in IOS/VoiceOver, so that part of the project is done and fairly straight-forward to accomplish in the IME framework.

Currently, Android's accessibility API doesn't provide accessible feedback for navigating text fields. That is, with an Android screen reader loaded, if you type the word "this", you'll hear individual characters spoken as you type them, but if you then try left-arrowing over the "s", that isn't spoken. So I want to trap movements and provide spoken feedback for the elements navigated past. Here's where I start encountering problems.

I currently have speech feedback for left and right arrowing, using getCurrentInputConnection.getTextBeforeCursor(1, 0) for arrowing left, and a similar call for arrowing right. This gets the character currently under the cursor after the movement is processed, and all is good.

My challenge, though, comes when arrowing up and down between lines. Ideally, I'd like to grab the current line of text and speak that, but I don't see any way to do that. The only thing I can think of is some combination of getTextBefore/AfterCursor(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 0) and combining those values, determining the current line by filtering for the previous and next \n. Is there another way--getting the entire text content of the field as a single block of text and using the cursor position to determine which piece of that text represents the current line? I'm seeing something about extracted text in the various input method classes, and it seems like there may be a way to monitor that, but I don't know if that is at all useful to me (I.e. would that return the entire field content?)

My next goal is providing standard text navigation capabilities. Android accessibility doesn't currently include touchscreen exploration, so it is impossible to otherwise scroll a large block of text. I don't necessarily expect folks to write novels on their phones, but I'd like to provide quick gestures or commands to move up/down paragraphs, and to the top/bottom of longer fields. Does the IMF provide methods for cursor movement, or is that outside of its authority?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I didn't get the first part :(

For your second question, you will need to handle it by hand.
For instance, to add a key with a down drawable and make it work you will need to:

- In the `onKey` method check for the code.
- If it's 20, you should do a `sendDownUpKeyEvents` of that key event.